# Unable to download Gstreamer package for RHEL 3.10 kernel, cannot use QWebView

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gstreamer, qwebkit, rhel7

I have a QT application that uses QWebView. On `RHEL7` with `3.10 kernel` I am getting following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstapp-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstinterfaces-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstpbutils-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstvideo-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstbase-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstreamer-0.10
```

On Ubuntu I dowloaded `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev` and it works fine.
On RHEL I have tried following packages but still getting the error:

- yum install gstreamer1-devel
- yum install gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel
- gstreamer010-0.10.13-3.4.x86_64.rpm
- gstreamer-plugins-ugly-0.10.19-17.el7.nux.src.rpm

`rpm -qa | grep gstreamer` this command gives following packages:
gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.0.7-4.el7.x86_64
gstreamer1-1.4.5-1.el7.x86_64
gstreamer-tools-0.10.36-7.el7.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-base-1.4.5-2.el7.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-good-1.0.7-5.el7.x86_64
gstreamer1-devel-1.4.5-1.el7.x86_64
gstreamer-0.10.36-7.el7.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel-1.4.5-2.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with gstreamer and plugins on debian. Linking was fine, but video player didn't show video with error that I have no required plugins. Finally I've installed packeges from ubuntu launchpad.

As I understand Qt uses 0.10 version of gstreamer and plugins, so installing gstreamer 1.0 won't help.  Since you use RHEL I guess the only way is to compile required packages by yourself. You can find sources [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/):

Comment: Thanks for help, as suggested by you I downloaded and build the gstreamer and plugins and installed them as mentioned in README. Still I was getting the error, but only for gstapp. When I investigaed more I came to know that in /user/local/lib folder **.a** for **gstapp** is missing. All other packages have respective .a. I tried some other minor versions of .10 package as well but of no use.